# Non-vanishing normal vector field on a closed 3D curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth regular simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does there always exist a smooth non-vanishing normal vector field on $C$? I.e. a smooth $n: C \to \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ such that $n(s)$ is perpendicular to the tangent vector at $s$ for every $s ∈ S$.

I know that if $Φ'' ≠ 0$ for some regular parametrization $Φ$, then Frenet frame works. Bishop frame works also when $Φ'' = 0$ somewhere, but I don't see why should the corresponding normal vector field be the same at the start point after a loop over the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right: The Bishop frame gives you a globally-defined frame only when the total twist of the curve is $0$ (i.e., if and only if $\displaystyle\int_C \tau\,ds$ is a multiple of $2\pi$).

However, you should be able to prove this just from differential topology. Here's one possible way. Pick a point $P\in\Bbb R^3$ that is not on any tangent line to the curve, and, using chords from points of $C$ to $P$, define a nowhere-zero normal vector field.